# Mortgage property

Tags: mortgage

My Husband and I bought a mortgage house in 50/50 partnership, I am not working and he is paying all costs. However he works out of town and decided to stay there. But he is still paying full installment, does that mean that he can own whole property afterwards?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Money.SE. What country are you in? What is a "mortgage house"? Are you simply referencing a house bought with downpayment and a loan? How was it 50/50? Did you put anything into the downpayment? There's far more missing here than actually written above.

Answer (score 3):

Ownership of the house is a separate issue than who is making the payments. So the answer to your question is that it depends.

Whoever is on the title owns the house. However, there are a few possible complications if you live in the US in a community property state. He might own half of the house regardless of what the paperwork says, but you'd need a lawyer to determine that.